# AngularJS Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular to pull content and display on some pages of the site. I have bootstrap drop-down menu in the header. Based on the user login in, some drop-down option are hidden. To achieve this, I used ng-if on the header controller. Everything working fine.

But the issue is, sometimes when I open the site I am able to see hidden drop-down options also and {{userRole}} is displayed as {{userRole}}. why is this happening? Thank you.

[Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMIay.png)
In the screen shot, user can see two my profile icons.

```
var itpApp = angular.module("itpApp",['ngRoute','angular.filter','ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
itpApp.controller("headerController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var gaR = new GlideAjax('ITPortalUtil0');  
  gaR.addParam('sysparm_name','u_role');  
  gaR.getXML(function(response) {
  $rootScope.userRole = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer"); 
  $rootScope.$apply();
  console.log('user role check: '+$rootScope.userRole);  
     //$rootScope.userRole = $localStorage.user_role;
     });
}); 


<div class="navbar navbar-default1" ng-controller="headerController">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="shortMenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

 <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Tickets$[SP]<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu7">

            <li ng-if="userRole =='ess'"><a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >My Profile</a></li>

            <li ng-if="userRole =='itil'"><a href="/portal/my_profile.do?sysparm_id=${user.sys_id}">My Profile</a></li>

          </ul>
 </li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: tip: 1. add `ng-cloak` on `<body>`.  2. use `ng-show`/ `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: I think the ajax request if get more time to take it will happen, so try to use promise for ajax request.

Comment: I tried ng-hide/ng-show no use. Still the issue occur sometimes.

Comment: Can anyone let me know how to use promise for ajax request in the above posted code??